# Ищу класс bootstrap#3, включающий свойство justify-content

Tags: css3, html5, bootstrap

Хочу сделать в bootstrap 3 то же самое, что в bootstrap 4 делается таким образом:

```
<div class="row justify-content-between">
    <div class="col-4">
      One of two columns
    </div>
    <div class="col-4">
      One of two columns
    </div>
</div>
```

Или, попросту, включить свойство `.row {justify-content: space-between;}`.
В доке в третьей версии вижу лишь вариант с оффсетом: `.col-md-offset-*` - это смотрится как костыль.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

bootstrap 3 не рассчитана на флекс.

Можно так:

```css
.row {
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  
  -ms-flex-pack: justify;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

  
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row justify-content-between">
        <div class="col-4">
          One of two columns
        </div>
        <div class="col-4">
          One of two columns
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

**P.S:** НО! Бессмысленное занятие переписывать стили из новой версии в старую, вместо того чтобы применить уже новую версию.

Comment: Я новичок в этом. Решил, что слово beta в названии версии - это не очень хорошо. Так же думал, что бутстрап изначально на флексах.

Comment: @AleksandrShemetillo, пользуюсь уже этой версией https://getbootstrap.com/ все очень просто и удобно. И флексы как раз только в 4-ой версии появились.

Comment: Ок, понял, спасибо.
Как раз только что разобрался, почему bower не ставит последнюю бету бутстрапа (и не будет ставить) и перешёл на неё. Так, действительно, проще.